# Makefiles: How to properly use $wildcard to recursively descend?

Tags: makefile

I have a folder of markdown files that are being converted to HTML files using a Makefile.  To figure out the source and dest, I use the following Makefile construct

`TARGETS_TO_BUILD := $(patsubst src/%.md, out/%.html, $(wildcard src/*.md src/**/*.md))`

If you echo out $(TARGETS_TO_BUILD) you get a list of paths `./out/index.html ./out/folder1/somepage.html` and so on.  Works fine.

However, if I start putting my source files into deeper and deeper folders, such that I end up with a deep tree, things stop working.  That wildcard (`src/**/*.md`) doesn't work. I have to start doing things like this:

`TARGETS_TO_BUILD := $(patsubst src/%.md, out/%.html, $(wildcard src/*.md src/**/*.md src/**/**/*.md src/**/**/**/*.md))`

I have to keep adding more and more of those.

That glob string isn't working as expected.  I thought they would work with infinite depth.

Comment: In [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt/blob/master/gmtt.mk) there are the `search-up` and `search-down` functions which find all files w/o intervention from the shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaken.  The [docs for wildcard support](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html) are quite clear on the syntax, and `**` is not listed.  `**` is an enhanced wildcard that is not supported by POSIX glob(3) and fnmatch(3) functions (which is what GNU make uses to implement globbing), and is not supported by POSIX sh.  In fact that syntax is not even available (by default) in `bash`, the standard shell in most GNU/Linux and MacOS systems.

In standard glob syntax, there is no difference between `*` and `**`.  In fact `***`, `****`, etc. all mean the same thing as `*`: there is no difference between matching zero or more characters once, twice, or 100 times.

If you want to recurse infinitely, the simplest thing to use is the `find` command via a `$(shell ...)` function:

```
TARGETS_TO_BUILD := $(patsubst src/%.md, out/%.html, $(shell find src -name '*.md' -print))
```